# Can anyone help me with setting folder permissions in IIS via an asp page?

Tags: security, asp-classic

I can create the folder, but I need to set the execute permissions to none/false for the folder named **files**. I have tried several examples on the net and none work correctly. Doing this manually in IIS is not an option, it must be done dynamically when the folder is created.

Here is what I use to create the folders:

set fso = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set folder3 = fso.CreateFolder(Server.MapPath(user_name & "/files"))

I found one example using an IIS Admin object, but it was a little over my head. I have full permission to make the directory change, just can't get the code right. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use PowerShell script depending on OS your're using

http://www.powershell.nu/2009/02/13/set-folder-permissions-using-a-powershell-script/